# what is [B >: A] "Lower Type Bounds"'s mean in scala? why child class obj can passed in too?

Tags: scala, lower-bound

There is a "Lower Type Bounds" in the :: method:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

[B >: A] **mean** B is the Parent class of A, but why the Child Class's object can passed in the :: method?

```
class GP
class P extends GP
class C extends P

val li : List[P] = List[P](new P)
(new GP)::li // ok
(new C)::li  // why here ok?
```

This `(ndw C)::li  // why here ok?`, (new C) is a obj of Child Class not Super class of P , is this not according with [B >: A])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, `C` is not a parent of (or equal to) `P`, so `C` can't be chosen as the value for `B`. However values of type `C` can be passed in to methods that expect values of type `P` (because `C` is a child class), so if we choose `B=P`, we get `::(x: P): List[P]` and `new C` can be passed in as the value for `x`. That's what happens when you do `(new C) :: li`.

That is why the resulting type is `List[P]` and not `List[C]` (which would be wrong), whereas the type of the previous line is `List[GP]` as on that line `B=GP` had to be chosen for the types to work out.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error because `(new C)` is an instance of `C`, and therefore of `P`; so, in that example, the `B` and `A` type-variables are both `P`.

(Your next question may be — if the lower type bound allows this, then what purpose does it serve? The answer is that it allows this:

```
val liC : List[C] = List[C](new C)
val liP : List[P] = (new P)::liC
```

(effectively "promoting" a `List[C]` to a `List[P]`) without allowing this:

```
val liP : List[P] = List[P](new P)
val liC : List[C] = (new C)::liP    // invalid! cannot downcast!
```

.)